# rails increment non-primary ID column in after create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to create a record and increment two non primary id columns in an after create callback with a integer and a date. The first column needs to be auto incremented with an integer from 1 to given number. The second column needs to be incremented with a date from the start date specified and by either 7, 14, or 30 days which is also specified. I tried creating the first record with the first value then incrementing from there but all records just have the same integer or date saved.

Here's the code

```
def create_positions
    @slots = (self.slots - 1)
    @payout_date = (self.start_date)
    @position = Position.create(:susu_id => self.id, :user_id => 2, :position_number => 1, :pay_in => self.contribution, :payout_date => (@payout_date + self.frequency_in_days.days))  
    @positions= self.positions.map { |p| p["position_number"] }.last.to_i
    @position_number = (@positions += 1)
    @dates = self.positions.map { |d| d["payout_date"] }.last
    @add_date = (@dates + self.frequency_in_days.days)
    @all_positions = @slots.times {Position.create(:susu_id => self.id, :user_id => 2, :position_number => @position_number, :pay_in => self.contribution, :payout_date => @add_date)   }
  end
```

What i get is: 1 2 2 2 and  1/2/14  1/9/14  1/9/14  1/9/14

instead of: 1 2 3 4 and 1/2/14 1/9/14 1/16/14 1/23/14

Comment: Just curious, what DB are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My lack of reputation prohibits me from commenting on your original post, so I'll just have to do my best to answer your question without asking for clarification (for I don't fully understand your explanation of what you're trying to do).

It sounds like you are trying to create four `Position` instances, each subsequent position having a position_number that is one greater than the previous one and having a payout_date that is 7 days later than the previous one.

If this is what you're trying to do, please [consider the following](http://plus4chan.org/b/cog/src/138445537462.gif):

```
# in the top of your susu model:
after_create :create_positions

# later in your susu model
def create_positions     
    4.times do |n|
        Position.create(susu: self,
                        user_id: 2,
                        position_number: n,
                        pay_in: contribution, 
                        payout_date: start_date + n * frequency_in_days.days)
    end
end
```

You have a lot of logic in your version of this method, so let me know if I have missed something that you need.

And finally, let me point out a few things about my version of this code:

- It uses Ruby 1.9 hash syntax ("`susu: self`" instead of "`:susu => self`")
- It removes unnecessary calls to `self`, which is considered [bad ruby style](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)
- It still has hardcoded `user_id: 2`, which seems like you're going to need to change at some point
- Doing this in an after_create hook will be in the same transaction as the original object being created. This means that if a Position cannot be created for whatever reason (e.g., a database-level unique key or a `validates_uniqueness_of` on the Position model failing), it will roll back the creation of the original object. If you don't like that behavior you can use the `after_commit` callback.

Cheers!

Comment: Thank you for answering the question. Maybe I don't understand something but in your code I don't see n defined or how n will be incremented for each record. Also, yes, Position cannot be created without Susu being created. That is by designed.

Comment: `n` will be incremented because `4.times` passes an integer to the block that starts at 0 and increases once per loop iteration. Here's an example from the ruby documentation that might help: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-times